# com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.unset

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Deploy a WAR MF application, but when I try to connect with a device:

```
/worklight/authorization/v1/clients/instance
```

**Error:**

> Context Root Not Found
>
> [8/29/15 14:20:49:378 CEST] 00000039 id=
>   com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger                  < startUp
>   RETURN [8/29/15 14:20:49:379 CEST] 00000039 id=
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator      I
>   contextInitialized.run FWLST0002I: ========= Project /worklight
>   started. The project WAR file version is
>   7.0.0.00.20150729-1801,running on server version 7.0.0.00.20150608-1356. [project worklight] [8/29/15 14:20:49:379 CEST] 00000039 id=
>   com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator      <
>   contextInitialized.runEnd init of worklight in 29448 sec RETURN
>   [8/29/15 14:20:49:379 CEST] 00000039 id=
>   com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal                   1 unset
>   unset ProjectLocal [project worklight] [8/29/15 14:20:49:380 CEST]
>   00000039 id=         com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal
>   3 unset java.lang.Throwable
>           at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.unset(BaseProjectLocal.java:114)
>           at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:283)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2388)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1048)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6404)

Comment: Provide the full messages.log file as well as server.xml file. Upload both to sites such as Google Docs, pastebin and alike.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that when deploying the .war file you provided an incorrect context root value, as the error suggests.

An attempt is make at `/worklight/authorization/v1/clients/instance`, where "worklight" is the context root, but the exception notes that a context root was not found.

You need to double-check your server.xml for correctness.
As suggested in the comments, to further diagnose the issue you need to supply your server.xml and full messages.log files.